# Can a kinged piece jump another king?

Tags: checkers

Can a kinged piece jump another king piece?

Comment: If a kinged piece could not be jumped, how would the game end?

Answer (score 6):

As was indicated by @JaysonSmith, a king can always be jumped by another king. This holds for any variant of [**draughts/checkers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts).

The privileges that a king obtains differ by variant, however.

- **backward movement**: in all variants, kings can move backward, but men cannot.
- **backward capture**: in all variants, kings can jump backward, but men cannot for American/English checkers/draughts, Italian, Spanish, Czech and Thai draughts.
- **long range movement and capture**: a king can move and capture long ranged (like a bishop in chess) for International, Frisian, Russian, Spanish, Czech and Thai draughts, as well as for Pool checkers, whereas men are short ranged in all variants.
- **invulnerable being captured by men**: a king cannot be jumped by men in Italian draughts.

Comment: Great answer, TemplateRex! You even covered the rules of Dominican Checkers that I used to play, called Taperos.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a kinged-piece can certainly jump another kinged-piece. In fact, having a kinged-piece does NOT make it invulnerable to being 'jump'. This means that even a NON-kinged-piece can jump a kinged-piece. The only advantage to kinging a piece is that it is able to move both Forward and Backward. A non-kinged-piece can be severely limited in jumping due to this rule. Thus, if a non-kinged piece were in position to jump three opponent's pieces in a row, but the second jump required the non-kinged piece to jump backwards, the non-kinged piece would have to resort to only jumping the first opponent's piece.